# problem with xepersian referencing

Tags: cross-referencing, xepersian

I'm writing my MSc thesis using LaTeX in Persian. When I use the XePersian package all the references including the number of sections, figures, equations, references disappear. Only the numbers of chapters are shown. I don't know what to do. When I remove the command `\usepackage{xepersian}` all the numbers come back but I cannot write in Persian.

I would be thankful if anyone can help me.

Comment: This is not normal behaviour of XePersian. Perhaps you did something wrong. Provide an MWE (minimal working example) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: @HasanZakeri: I even tried a simple example in the XePersian manual and its not working:

`1 \documentclass{article}`
`2 \usepackage{xepersian}`
`3 \settextfont{XB Niloofar}`
`4 \title{ {یک سند نمونه`
`5 \author{ {نام نویسنده`
`6 \begin{document}`
`7 \maketitle`
`8 \tableofcontents`
`9 \part{ {عنوان بخش`
`10 ...`
`11 \section{ {عنوان قسمت`
`12 ...`
`13 \subsection{ {عنوان زیرقسمت`
`14 ...`
`15 \subsubsection{ {عنوان زیر زیرقسمت`
`16 ...`
`17 \end{document}`

Comment: @HasanZakeri: I was wondering whether if the problem is the distribution of TEX. I'm using currently MiKTeX 2.9, should I try TeX Live?

Comment: Update all of your packages (including XePersian and bidi) and tex distribution.

Comment: @smh: I tried upgrading the packages and bidi. It's not working, and it gets worse when I upgrade the packages by receiving lots of error! I'm trying to upgrade TEX distribution.

Comment: Never update a single package alone. Update your whole tex distribution. Also, MikTeX uses a bit older version of xetex engine that might cause some problems. Try the latest version of texlive, and if the problem persists, feel free to ask.

Comment: BTW, check out www.parsilatex.com.

Comment: @HasanZakeri: Thanks, it's gonna take a while to download TeXLive. I'll let you know ASAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my TeX distribution to TeX Live and the problem was solved!

thanks to Hasan Zakeri and smh.